# Is there any class name conventions for pre-integration-test and post-integration-test similar to integration-test

Tags: java, maven

For junit test cases The class should be named like XXTest.java

For intergation-test the class should be named like XXIT.java

Is there any class name conventions for pre-integration-test and post-integration-test goals in maven similar to unit and integration test?

Comment: I hereby invite you to invent your own naming convention for these.

Comment: I have the unit tests in the module I am testing and integration tests is their own module which depends on all the modules I have looking to test the integration of.

Answer (score 2):

The convention is that no tests of any kind are run during pre- and post-integration-test.

As suggested by @biziclop, the way to think about this is "pre-X" and "post-X"  - these are things executed before/after "X". So, pre-integration-test phase is not the phase where "pre-integration" tests are run, but rather it is the phase before "integration-test" is run.

These goals are usually used for managing system state for the running of integration tests. For example, pre-integration-test may start a container that is used by the integration tests, while post-integration-test will stop the container.

There is nothing wrong with using a variety of plugins and/or custom code to support the execution of your integration tests. If using exec-maven-plugin really bothers you, you can always create your own maven plugin that knows about whatever naming convention you want to use to find java classes in your build and execute them. Then each of your modules can use the generic plugin to invoke the specific set of classes to do the setup/tear-down.

Comment: So `pre-integration-test` means `pre-(integration-test)` and not `(pre-integration)-test`.

Comment: @Rob In my case I have to do multiple things, so I have written java classes and running them using exec-maven-plugin. But that feels me like I am not doing it in a proper way. I am trying to find Is there any way that I can just add the class and it gets run in the pre/post integration-test goals with out adding any plugins in pom.xml

Comment: @biziclop Yes. Well-said. Thanks.